# Get Radial Gradient in UWP XAML

Tags: xaml, uwp

Linear Gradient in UWP XAML works fine but I need to convert it to Radial Gradient brush.

Here is my current UWP XAML code

```
<Page
    x:Class="button_radious.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:button_radious"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="1,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#000000" Offset="0.30"/>
            <GradientStop Color="green" Offset="0.65"/>
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.90"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Grid.Background>    
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Could you please add some more informationsto your question. For example what the given code does and what the problem is with the code

Answer (score 5):

`RadialGradientBrush` is not included by default as UWP API. You will need to add reference to the [**Windows Community Toolkit UI** - `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/) which contains [`RadialGradientBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/brushes/radialgradientbrush) which you can use as expected, the same way as in WPF.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Background>
    <media:RadialGradientBrush 
            AlphaMode="Premultiplied"
            RadiusX="0.2" RadiusY="0.2"
            SpreadMethod="Reflect">
        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0" />
        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.25" />
        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.50" />
        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.75" />
        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1.0" />
    </media:RadialGradientBrush>
  </Grid.Fill>
</Grid>
```

Because the brush resides in the library, you will have to add the following namespace declaration to your `Page` element:

```
xmlns:media="Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Media"
```

Comment: I install the nuget package and declare it to my page declaration but it still does not exists. There is nothing other than "this does not exists".

Comment: As the documentation mentions, you should now use `RadialGradientBrush` from WinUI instead - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.media.radialgradientbrush?view=winui-2.8 . Install the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` NuGet and then use `xmls:media="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media"`